# String to Object conversion?

Tags: javascript, regex, json, string

I have a string variable that is a string representation of an object. Like this:

```
{
    "column": "'asdf'",
    "sort": "true",
    "search": "{\"asdf\":\"searchval\"}"
}
```

I would like to transform the above string into an object that looks like this:

```
{
    column: 'asdf',
    sort: 'true',
    search: {
        asdf: 'searchval'
    }
}
```

I am planning on doing a search and replace regex expression for quotes and back slashes, and then using eval(), but that seems unsafe and innefficient. Is there an alternative method that would work better?

I am planning on assigning the object value of the string to an object variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried JSON.parse(); yet?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
var myOriginalData = JSON.stringify({"column": "'asdf'","sort": "true","search": "{\"asdf\":\"searchval\"}"});

myNewData = JSON.parse(myOriginalData, function (key, value) {
    var type;
    if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
        type = value.type;
        if (typeof type === 'string' && typeof window[type] === 'function') {
            return new (window[type])(value);
        }
    }
    return value;
});

console.log('myNewData -----------------------------------------------------------');
console.log(myNewData);
```

**Working Example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2jLGIxx3AVEceVQsOpxL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after posting this, I found out there is a `JSON.parse();` function. The only reason I don't delete the question, is it might save someone time later.

All you need to do is pass the string variable as a parameter and it will output an object.

If anyone sees any problems with this solution, or knows a better solution, please make an answer!

Comment: i posted a full working example above if you were still interested.